# How can i trigger a change on my device once another device scans a qrcode on my device in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter and I am trying to create two apps where one generates a qr code and the other scans the qr code. Generating or scanning is not my issue but I would love to trigger a state change in the generating app only when the scanning app successfully scans the the qr code on the generating app. Any ideas on how to achieve this on flutter?

Comment: Upon successfully scanning the barcode you can update the database of the individual generating the barcode to scanned and using that state probably update your display...

Comment: What would be the latency for doing this coz I need it to be almost instant if not instant

Comment: It won't be that high, you can try this...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do that with a database... When the User scans a code, it sends a message to the database wich triggers the other app, wich is listening for a signal like that in the background. If you don't have a database, you can use Firebase, Firebase is very fast with something like that

But this solution has a disadvantage: It would only work online.

Hope you find a solution :)